# PhoneGap App: jQuery getJSON getting 404 error when getting local file with relative URL

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have an HTML/JavaScript app that I'm trying to convert to an App using PhoneGap via the [Phonegap Build app](http://build.phonegap.com)

Everything works fine through the browser, and the only problem the app is having is that the call to `getJSON` is returning a 404 error when trying to load my local resources.

Here is the culprit:

```
$.getJSON( "./shapes/json/" + abbr + '.json', gotJSON(abbr) );
```

I have whitelisted every domain, just to be sure:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Is this something that is not possible from the phonegap environment?  Or am I doing something wrong?

If needed, I can host the files elsewhere and do a cross-domain ajax call, but I'd rather have the files right there on the device.

This is currently happening on Android, which is the only system I can test at the moment.

**UPDATE:**

I'm now trying:

```
    var xhrShapes = new XMLHttpRequest(), xhrSuccess = gotJSON(abbr);

    xhrShapes.open('GET', config.path + "/shapes/json/" + abbr + ".json");
    xhrShapes.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if( this.readyState === 4 ){
            if( this.status === xhrSuccessCode ){
                xhrSuccess(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
        }
    }
    xhrShapes.send();
```

`config.path` is "file:///android_asset/www" and I'm getting `0` as a success code (which indicates success for 'file://' requests).  but `xhrShapes.responseText` is blank and everything stops at the call to `JSON.parse`.  I feel like I'm missing something simple...

Comment: "./shapes" => "../shapes"?

Comment: The single dot is correct.  The `shapes` folder is in the same folder as the index.html that is running the JavaScript.  I'm dynamically adding an image and setting the `src`, which works, so I'm guessing it's some kind of issue with the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the code, but rather with the file names being case-sensitive...  my `abbr` variable was uppercase, but filenames are lowercase.  `$.getJSON` works perfectly, now that I've corrected this (though now my pride needs some repairs).